# categorical IVs, continuous moderator and DV - statistical test

Tags: self-study, categorical-data, interaction, experiment-design, continuous-data

I'm planning an experimental research. My research question is when do my treatments could be effective in influencing intention. Below are variables to be set.

- treatments / scenarios / IVs: 3 categorical variables (a, b, c), each of them has 2 levels
- moderator: 1 continuous moderator
- DV (i.e., intention): 1 continuous DV

If I use linear regression for the dataset, is it that I will have 15 predictor variables as below:

1. dummy a
2. dummy b
3. dummy c
4. dummy a * dummy b
5. dummy a * dummy c
6. dummy b * dummy c
7. dummy a * dummy b * dummy c
8. continuous moderator
9. dummy a * moderator
10. dummy b * moderator
11. dummy c * moderator
12. dummy a * dummy b * moderator
13. dummy a * dummy c * moderator
14. dummy b * dummy c * moderator
15. dummy a * dummy b * dummy c * moderator

Any suggestions?

Comment: 1) What is your research question? In other words, why do this experiment at all? 2) What question do you have about that second bullet point?

Comment: @Dave sorry my bad. I've improved the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you include all interactions in your model, you are correct. In unpenalized linear regression with this type of study you typically need about 10-20 cases per predictor to avoid overfitting. You should make sure to have a total of 150-300 cases, if you want to include all interactions and don't want to use a penalized regression method.

Comment: many thanks for the suggestion. For a total of 150-300 cases, do you mean for the whole sample or for each treatment group? (ps. I have 8 treatment groups / manipulated conditions in total)

Comment: @James for the whole sample. With a designed experiment it's usually best to have equal numbers in all treatment groups. With 8 treatment groups (all combinations of three 2-level interventions) that would be 20-40 per group. That's just to avoid overfitting. Power analysis might indicate more, depending on the magnitudes of differences you want to detect and the estimated variability in responses under the same treatment. See Frank Harrell's [course note](http://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) and [book](https://hbiostat.org/rms/) for extensive guidance.

Comment: appreciate your guidance. Very useful!

Comment: one more last question. Can I use ANCOVA to do the analysis? More specifically, in SPSS univariate GLM, can I treat the continuous IV as covariate and categorical IVs as fixed factor and specify all subordinate interactions and higher order interactions by clicking custom model button? Many thanks!

Comment: @James I don't use SPSS, but that seems like it should work. Be careful in interpreting the regression coefficients, however, as they represent associations with outcome that only hold under specific conditions. For example, the `dummy a` coefficient will only hold when all the other dummies are at reference levels and the continuous predictor is at 0. See [this page](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/spss/library/spss-libraryhow-do-i-handle-interactions-of-continuous-andcategorical-variables/) and its links.

Comment: thanks for your advice! Will study the suggested webpage carefully.